# Running .pkg on MAC OS from java code

Tags: java, macos

Am trying to run a .mpkg application from my java code :

```
public void runNewPkg(){

try {

           String command = "sudo installer -pkg Snip.mpkg -target /Applications";
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            System.out.println(p.getErrorStream());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And am getting the following error and my terminal window hangs..

```
java.lang.UNIXProcess$DeferredCloseInputStream@2747ee05
Password:
Sumit-Ghoshs-iMac-3:downloads sumitghosh3$ Password:
Password:
-bash: **********: command not found

Sumit-Ghoshs-iMac-3:downloads sumitghosh3$
```

- I Think i need to provide the password also to run the pkg from the command line
  Could you tell me how i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually try editing your /etc/sudoers file to not prompt for a password. If you use the NOPASSWD tag, you should be able to do that. An example entry would be:

```
sumitghosh3 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 2):

You can provide the password to sudo:

```
echo "p@sw0rd" | sudo -S cal -y 2011
```

The command above runs 'cal -y 2011' with root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an interactive solution for elevating privilege, I have used `openscript` to elevate privilege of a wrapped shell script.  It goes something like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.MessageFormat;

/**
 * OsxExecutor.java
 */
public class OsxExecutor {

    private String error = null;
    private String output = null;

    /**
     * Privileged script template format string.
     * Format Arguments:
     * <ul>
     * <li> 0 = command
     * <li> 1 = optional with clause
     * </ul>
     */
    private final static String APPLESCRIPT_TEMPLATE = 
        "osascript -e ''try''"
        + " -e ''do shell script \"{0}\" {1}''" 
        + " -e ''return \"Success\"''" 
        + " -e ''on error the error_message number the error_number'' "
        + " -e ''return \"Error: \" & error_message''"
        + " -e ''end try'';";


    public void executeCommand(String command, boolean withPriviledge) {
        String script = MessageFormat.format(APPLESCRIPT_TEMPLATE,
                                             command,
                                             withPriviledge
                                              ?  "with administrator privileges"
                                               : "");
        File scriptFile = null;
        try {
            scriptFile = createTmpScript(script);
            if (scriptFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            // run script
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(scriptFile.getAbsolutePath());

            StreamReader outputReader = new StreamReader(p.getInputStream());
            outputReader.start();
            StreamReader errorReader = new StreamReader(p.getErrorStream());
            errorReader.start();

            int result = p.waitFor();

            this.output = outputReader.getString();
            if (result != 0) {
                this.error = "Unable to run script " 
                    + (withPriviledge ? "with administrator privileges" : "") 
                    + "\n" + script + "\n"
                        + "Failed with exit code: " + result
                        + "\nError output: " + errorReader.getString();
                return;
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            this.error = "Unable to run script:\n" + script
                    + "\nScript execution "
                    + (withPriviledge ? " with administrator privileges" : "") 
                    + " failed: " + e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            if (scriptFile.exists()) {
                scriptFile.delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If `withPriviledge` flag is true, a password dialog will be raised.  Not shown is `createTmpScript()` which creates an executable file in `/tmp`, and `StreamReader` which extends `Thread` and is used to capture both `stdout` and `stderr` streams.