# MAC command to run a .pkg file on terminal

Tags: macos

I have a .mpkg file which i want to execute from the terminal
I sucessfully used this command to achive this

```
sudo installer -pkg Snip.mpkg -target /Applications
```

But the thing is that when i run this command it ask me for the admin password before performing the installation.
Is there a way i can do this without the password or can i provide the password also in my sudo installer command...

Also see :- [Running .pkg on MAC OS from java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297647/running-pkg-on-mac-os-from-java-code)

please reply

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running .pkg on MAC OS from java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297647/running-pkg-on-mac-os-from-java-code)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the password requirement from [sudo](http://www.sudo.ws/) using the following line in sudoers:

```
jinith ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Do note the other solution will add the password to the process list. Mine will make it so that user jinith can run **any** command as **any** user without a password.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass in the password from `stdin`:

```
echo <password> | sudo -S installer -pkg Snip.mpkg -target /Applications
```