# Running a .pkg installer on Mac OSX through java applet

Tags: java, macos, installation, applet

Here is a short synopsis of what's going on.

Right now I have a java applet that is embedded in my browser that downloads a .dmg disk image and mounts it. Inside of it, it has an `installer.pkg` file that I need to be able to run so that the user begins to see the install process. I have been trying a few variations of what was provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297647/running-pkg-on-mac-os-from-java-code) but I believe that is only from the terminal.

Essentially, I need to be able to run the .pkg file inside of the mounted disk image not using the terminal. Thanks!

Comment: *"I need to be able to, after I have mounted the.."* ..question?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by simply using the open command for anyone who is interested. Here is a snippet of code that fixed it:

```
Process proc = r.exec(new String[] {"open", "/Volumes/HomeDrive/HomeInstaller.pkg"});
int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
```